# Flask Based app raising PyMongo Error in Heroku

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, heroku, mongodb-atlas

I've deployed my beginner Flask based app to Heroku. I've hosted my database in MongoDB Atlas. When I browse the website it works fine. But when I try to pass any data to MongoDB Atlas through this app it raise errors. I've checked the logs and this is what I've found.

```
2020-12-04T11:43:03.030523+00:00 app[web.1]: pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: connection closed,connection closed,connection closed, Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 5fca1c3a1f28e76a96f5a9a7, topology_type: ReplicaSetNoPrimary, servers: [<ServerDescription ('cluster0-shard-00-00.roavi.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('connection closed',)>, <ServerDescription ('cluster0-shard-00-01.roavi.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('connection closed',)>, <ServerDescription ('cluster0-shard-00-02.roavi.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('connection closed',)>]>
```

But this app runs fine locally and shows now error. Here is the *rquirements.txt* file:

```
Flask==1.1.2
flask_pymongo==2.3.0
gunicorn==20.0.4
dnspython==2.0.0
```

Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn -b :$PORT "arvtonline:create_app()"
```

*__init*__.py

```py
from flask import Flask
from .admin.routes import admin
from .general.routes import site
from .extensions import mongo

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    #reginstering admin and site to the blue print
    app.register_blueprint(admin)
    app.register_blueprint(site)

    #connecting MongoDB
    app.config['MONGO_URI'] ="mongodb+srv://arvtonline:************@cluster0.roavi.mongodb.net/arvtdb?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
    mongo.init_app(app)
    
    return app
```

So the problem is with database part only. Is the problem with MongoDB Atlas? They why does it work locally? How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: 1. Try to run your app im Docker, does it work? 
2. Check the whitelist IPs in Atlas.

Comment: I don't use docker. But IP whitelisting has solved my problem. I have Allowed Access from Anywhere, and it has added IP 0.0.0.0/0 in the list. Is it the right way, or should I just add the IP of the Heroku's app site IP? You can consider writing it as an answer as it can be a common issue with deploying app in Heroku.